# Delete Record in Emberjs

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I am struggling to follow [ember 2.0's documentation](http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.0.0/models/creating-updating-and-deleting-records/) for deleting records and then redirecting to a new url. When I try, I get the following error to the console:

```
Error while processing route: pencils Attempted to handle event `pushedData` on <name-emberjs@model:pencil::ember523:null> while in state root.deleted.inFlight.  Error: Attempted to handle event `pushedData` on <name-emberjs@model:pencil::ember523:null> while in state root.deleted.inFlight.
```

My files follow.

Routes:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import config from './config/environment';

var Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: config.locationType
});

Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('pencilview', { path: '/pencils/:pencil_id' });
    this.resource('pencilcreate', { path: '/pencils/new' });
    this.resource('pencils');
});


export default Router;
import Ember from 'ember';
import config from './config/environment';

var Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: config.locationType
});

Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('pencilview', { path: '/pencils/:pencil_id' });
    this.resource('pencilcreate', { path: '/pencils/new' });
    this.resource('pencils');
});


export default Router;
```

routes/pencilview.js

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
      return this.store.find('pencil', params.pencil_id);
    },

    actions: {
        save(pencil){
            this.store.find('pencil', pencil.id).then(function(pencil){
                pencil.save();
            })
            this.transitionTo('pencils');
        },

        remove(id){
            this.get('store').find('pencil', id).then(function(pencil2){
                pencil2.destroyRecord();
            });
            this.transitionTo('pencils');
        },

      cancel(pencil){
          this.store.find('pencil'.pencil.id).then(function(pencil){
          })
      }
  }
});
```

templates/pencilview.hbs

```
<h2>Single Pencil View</h2>
<p>Pencil ID: {{model.id}}</p>

<p>
<label for='name'>Name</label>
{{input type="text" id="name" value=model.name}}</p>

<p>
<label for='name2'>Name2</label>
{{input type="text" id="n2" value=model.n2}}</p>

<p>
<label for='name3'>Name3</label>
{{input type="text" id="n3" value=model.n3}}</p>

<p><button {{action "remove" model.id}}>Delete</button></p>
<p><button {{action "save" model}}>Save</button></p>

{{#link-to 'pencils'}}Pencils{{/link-to}}
```

controllers/*

```
all missing except for pencilcreate.js, not applicable here
```

template/pencils.hbs

```
<h2>All Pencils</h2>
<p>{{#link-to 'pencilcreate' (query-params direction='pencils') class='btn btn-default' }}Create New Pencil{{/link-to}}</p>

<table id='pencil_allTable' class='display'>
<thead><tr><td>ID</td><td>Brand</td><</tr></thead>
<tbody>
{{#each model as |pencil|}}
  <tr>
    <td>{{#link-to "penciliew" pencil class='btn btn-default'}}{{pencil.id}}{{/link-to}}</td>
    <td>{{pencil.brand}}</td>
  </tr>
{{/each}}
</tbody></table>

<script>
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#pencil_allTable').DataTable();
    } );
</script>
```

routes/pencil.js

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    return this.store.findAll('pencil');
  }  
});
```

Comment: It seems that both Henry and torazaburo's answers do not update my drugs view. That is, the `delete api` is hit, but the store is not updated. When transitioning to `pencils`, it shows the old data unless I refresh the page. I will award the bounty to whomever updates their answer and solves this final puzzle piece first. If a new answer jumps in with a conglomerate of those listed below, I will check mark it and give Henry the bounty.

Comment: I see nothing anywhere about any `drugs` view. If you mean `pencils`, please show the route, controller ,and template.

Comment: My guess is that your server is not deleting the record properly. So the `findAll` is bringing it back. Please consult your server logs etc., examine your database, etc. Perhaps there's some kind of caching somewhere along the line.

Comment: Also, check the network payload resulting from the `findAll`. I preduct you'll find it contains the allegedly deleted pencil.

Comment: Check the response of your server. It should return a 200 with an empty valid json response or a 204 with no response.

Comment: Server deletes everything correctly. If I refresh the page, the record disappears from my table. But it's not leaving the the store?...

Comment: You can force your model to retrieve always fresh data by `this.store.findAll('pencil', { reload: true });`

Comment: @mh00h: have you found a solution for this problem.I face the same problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39193633/attempted-to-handle-event-pusheddata-on-appnamemodelpostember62217-whil

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a version of another answer, just tightened up a bit.

```
remove(id) {
  this.get('store').find('pencil', id) . 
    then(pencil2 => pencil2.destroyRecord())
    .then(() => this.transitionTo('pencils'));
}
```

Comment: please see my comment above for a further refinement request of your answer.

Answer (score 3):

You've been bitten by `this` scope in:

```
this.transitionTo('pencils').then(function(id){
    this.get('store') // <== this === undefined
```

This code should work:

```
remove(id) {
    this.get('store').find('pencil', id).then(pencil2 => {
        pencil2.deleteRecord();
    });
    this.transitionTo('pencils');
},
```

Comment: This is leading to a `GET http://0.0.0.0:6543/api/pencils/%3Cname-emberjs%40route%3Apencils%3A%3Aember590%3E 500 (Internal Server Error)`. I'm wondering if save() needs to be run before the transitionTo as well but this creates a different problem: `Error while processing route: pencils Attempted to handle event pushedData on <name-emberjs@pencil::ember549:3> while in state root.deleted.inFlight.  Error: Attempted to handle event pushedData on <name-emberjs@model:pencil::ember549:3> while in state root.deleted.inFlight.`

Comment: Answer updated. You can't fetch deleted record, so you can't save it after it has been deleted.

Comment: This only partially works. calling deleteRecord() doesn't send the `DELETE` request to the api; it only affects the local store. Changing `deleteRecord()` to `destroyRecord()` causes it to bug out again, logging `root.deleted.inFlight` error.

Answer (score 3):

Let the promise fulfil itself:

```
remove(id){
        this.get('store').find('pencil', id).then((pencil2) => {
            pencil2.destroyRecord().then(() => {
               this.transitionTo('pencils');
           });
        });           
    },
```

Edit: getting rid of the `const _this`.

Comment: Good answer, plus one, but minor nitpicking, since we went to all the trouble to be able to use ES6 and fat arrows, can't we tighten up the code and get rid of `_this` all at the same time? Also, it might be slightly more readable to string out the `then`s instead of nesting them.

Comment: please see my comment above for a further refinement request of your answer.