# Attempted to handle event `pushedData` on <appname@model:post::ember622:17> while in state root.deleted.inFlight

Tags: node.js, ember.js

I have a basic crud app for blog posts.The above error shows up in the console.After I delete the post.But the post gets deleted from the database.I searched for similar questions and none of the answers solved the issue.I use **JSONAPIAdapter** for the crud actions.

> I checked the ember inspector for the flags and the flag for **isDeleted** is set to **true**.FYI the number of **records** shown in *ember data* is precise.

```
deletePost:function(id){
  var self = this;
  this.get('store').find('post', id)
    .then(post => post.destroyRecord())
      .then(() => self.transitionToRoute('posts'));
}
```

I use nodejs as backend and mysql as db.After deleting the record I send a response like this `res.status(204).end();`

> **Ember CLI version 2.6.3**

[image]

The above details in the image is the response from the server.
[image]

Comment: first check with store using peekRecord method and if its not found then initiate findRecord..this problem very well explained this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38424030/delete-request-is-completing-before-get-request-when-trying-to-findrecord-and-de

Comment: @kumkanillam: not working..

Comment: A couple things: 1st. You're using `find()` instead of `findRecord()`, that might somehow help. 2nd, please post the order that the api requests get made. I would expect there to be 3 requests. 1 to find the original record, 2nd to delete, then 3rd when you transition.

Comment: the same error occurs for both find() and findRecord().The order of api requests is as you stated.Find Record -> Delete Record(the error occurs after deleting the record) -> Transition to route.

Comment: Even I tried replacing `destroyRecord()` with `post.deleteRecord()` then `post.save()`.Same error occurs.Create,Update,Edit works perfectly without any errors FYI.

Comment: if its feasible then you can try by sending record itself instead of id for `deletePost` method. time being :) ..like @xcskier56 mentioned pls provide network request details.

Comment: @vishwas Does it throw an error if you do not transition to the `posts` route? Or, stated differently, if you remove the second `then` clause with the `transitionToRoute()`, does it still produce the error?

Comment: @xcskier56: even if i don't transition it causes the same error.

Comment: @vishwas Ok, so we know for sure that the issue is the `find` request not the `transition`. That's helpful.

Comment: @xcskier56: i have added a photo regarding the response from the server and the complete error message.

Comment: after delete  request does it send get request for the same id

Comment: @kumkanillam: no it is not making any get request after delete.I checked the network tab.A similar question which doesn't have any asnwers solving the problem.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32851565/delete-record-in-emberjs

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that this issue is being caused by ember data's background reload. Even though the find request to the api is triggered before the delete request, the find request is resolving after you've triggered the delete request. To disable background reload and force an api call you can pass `{reload: true}` to the `findRecord()` call. This will ensure that the find request resolves before you trigger the delete request.

Like this:

```
deletePost(id) {
  this.get('store').findRecord('post', id, { reload: true }).then((post) => { 
    return post.destroyRecord();
  }).then(() => {
    self.transitionToRoute('posts');
  });
}
```

You can read more about `findRecord` here: http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_findRecord

In the future, I'd recommend not using the arrow function shorthand since it will always return even when you don't want to a return value.

Answer (score 0):

I've come here a couple of different times looking for the solution. I actually found a better answer [here](https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/4714). The approach they recommend is to use a peekRecord instead of a findRecord (assuming the item is already in the store), which will be synchronous. The code from there:

```
// get the comment from the store synchronously, without triggering a fetch
let comment = store.peekRecord("comment", commentId);

// check if there is a comment; is null in the case the store has no comment 
with the given id
if (comment) {
    comment.destroyRecord(...);
}
```

This worked for me, where the `{reload: true}` did not.